# json path syntax to sort the values

Tags: json, robotframework

I am doing API testing in my current project. I got this below json data to validate some of the table values. But I don’t know how to sort volumes  region should be sorted in ascending order.

```
 {
    "type": "Financial Risk",
    "category_volume_list": [{
                "category_type": "Volume as Acquirer",
                "volumes": [{
                            "region": "NA",
                            "volume": 1279550601.24,
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        {
                            "region": "EUR",
                            "volume": 1642489095.24,
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        {
                            "region": "LAC",
                            "volume": 3149627.36,
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        {
                            "region": "CEMEA",
                            "volume": 1106493.08,
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        {
                            "region": "AP",
                            "volume": 118011586.85,
                            "currency": "USD"
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
import json
from jsonpath_ng import parse

json_data = json.loads(json_string)
jsonpath_expression = parse('$..region')
region_list_origin = [match.value for match in jsonpath_expression.find(json_data)]
region_list_copy = region_list_origin.copy()
region_list_copy.sort()
print(region_list_origin) //['NA', 'EUR', 'LAC', 'CEMEA', 'AP']
print(region_list_copy)   //['AP', 'CEMEA', 'EUR', 'LAC', 'NA']
```